# Qr Code Reader Android - To read IOS generated QR s

Tags: android, ios, qr-code

My current QR code reader picks only android generated Qrs. 
I would appreciate if anyone can give me an advise or a link for a resource that how to pick ios generated qr codes using an android qr reader

basically i use this

in my scan button >  onClick

```
myview.setOnQRCodeReadListener(MyActivity.this);
```

and in my QR code reader I use this method to pick the qr

```
@Override
public void onQRCodeRead(String text, PointF[] pointFs) {

}
```

and I am using 
compile `'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:1.0.0'`
in my dependencies

How can I pick an iOS generated QR code?

Comment: QR codes should be the same whether they're from iOS or Android. Can you upload a sample code?